# Does a Windows service have to be its own exe?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, windows, service

In short, what I'm trying to do is include Windows Services that run when ASP.NET MVC application starts and which are defined inside that MVC solution.

I have a class

```
public class PageRetriever : ServiceBase
{
    // ... 
}
```

that I defined in

```
MyMvcProject/Services/PageRetriever.cs
```

and I have try to start the service in my app start like

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        ServiceBase.Run(new PageRetriever());
    }
```

but when I build-and-run I get the error

[image]

Why's that, and what should I be doing instead?

Comment: Passing observation: Your ASP.NET application already kind of 'is' a service; why do you need it to start another one? Typically it'll be a service which already exists or you need the isolation, but it seems to be neither of those.

Comment: what is the requirement of start windows service on ASP.NET MVC application starts? why you can't to the same operations on mvc application?

Comment: @Damith I have a task that kicks off at set intervals and it makes more sense for it to be separate from my mode-view-controller workflow

Comment: @user7127000 Use a [timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). This is a non-answer to the actual question (yes) but it's probably the solution you'd be best using.

Comment: @LukeBriggs I am using a System.Timer -- in the service I'm trying to write

Comment: Separate windows service is all right but the starting and installing windows service from web application is something you need to revisit. web applications run on isolated/restricted permission set, in case of this kind of task you may need to set higher lever permissions for the application pool identity. why don't you write record to database when your web site start, you can check the same table from another windows service periodically

Comment: @user7127000 why would it need to be in a service at all? Your ASP application is already running anyway - it's start the timer vs starting a separate service (which in turn starts the timer). Starting a timer is simpler and generally more efficient anyway as you won't have to deal with inter-process comms.

Comment: You cannot start a windows service without installing it firstly. The error is clear about this. And like others have said, what you are doing is pretty strange. So I would rethink the design

Comment: **WARNING**: he's spamming the same question all over again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822963/is-it-possible-for-me-to-create-a-windows-service-in-visual-studio-web-2013